# springSecurityFilterChain how it works?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I try to implement my own filter in spring framework using `springSecurityFilterChain`. I would implement that filter in spring content, no in *web.xml*. In *web.xml* I would just use one filter which will delegate all reqeust to filters located in spring content. For example:

My web.xml file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Now all request will delegate to filters located in spring content.

Ok so we start to create a bean filter class which implement `Filter`:

```
package myapplication.filters

public class ExampleFilter implements Filter {

    private ServletContext context;

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        // some code here
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // some filter here
    }

    public void destroy() {
        //we can close resources here
    }
```

Now I would use my filter to call `doFilter` method when some (human or other application) want get resource from url: */example*. So we need to configure spring in *secruity.xml* file. At this step I would add I dont want authorize using html from. I will get params like username and password from approaching POST request

My secruity.xml:

```
 <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" >

    <!-- 
       HERE I DECLARE MY CUSTOM FILTER BU WHERE IS PATTERN.
       FROM WHERE SPRING WILL KNOWN THAT IF REQUEST COME /example
       THAN CALL METHOD doFilter FROM CLASS myapplication.filters.ExampleFilter
     -->
    <custom-filter ref="ExampleFilter " />


</http>

 <bean id="ExampleFilter " class="myapplication.filters.ExampleFilter"></bean>
```

Comment: And why is your filter different from the normal filter that handles post requests to `j_spring_security_check`? That basically does what you want...